# Identification of shelf brackets

Tags: cabinets, shelving, hardware, brackets

I have a steel sheet metal cabinet that uses the pictured brackets to hold up shelves. It has a runner in each corner on the inside, with slots which the brackets fit into with a little tooth on the back, which is 3/8" wide (shown below). The shelf sits on top of them. Similar to a push in shelf bracket. I would like to install some more shelves, but do not know what the brackets are called, preventing me from getting some more. Can these be identified to assist in purchasing some?

brackets installed into slots
[image: brackets installed into slots]

top of brackets
[image: top of brackets]

back of bracket showing tooth
[image: back of bracket showing tooth]

bottom of bracket showing tooth
[image: bottom of bracket showing tooth]

Comment: If they are old, then you may find getting them made or making them is a quicker option...

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the term "shelf clips" I was able to locate only one resource, a company called [Locksco](http://www.locksco.com/default.aspx?page=item%20detail&itemcode=AMSP0169) which has a clip that appears to be similar to yours.

[image: shelf clip]

During the search, I saw also the term "metal cabinet shelf clips" but using that search term did not present the previous location/link. At US$20 for quantity four, they certainly are expensive.

Note also that no references of scale are apparent. They could be too small or too large for your purpose.

Additional searches proved fruitless.

Comment: At that price, I would be buying a few hacksaw blades...

Comment: Yes, at that price, a piece of flat bottom steel U-channel and the saw would make short work of the brackets. Maybe a dremel cutter for faster results.

Comment: A $15 angle grinder and a 1mm cut-off wheel, even faster

Comment: The angle grinder & cutoff wheel option, @Jasen, would also make quick work of a section of steel U-channel while a novice user learned his trade...