# Shelf Bracket Identification?

Tags: metal, brackets, shelf

Can anyone please help me identify the name of this bracket so that I can order more for my metal cupboard?

Thanks! [image]

Comment: It doesn't really have a name. In all likelihood It's bespoke to the cupboard manufacturer, so your best course of action is to contact them directly, I'd think.

Comment: This isn't _really_ a duplicate of [this other question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/170300), but the answer there (and, more importantly, the comments) is probably about the best you're going to get.

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing how this bracket is used (maybe it's just me). A picture of the bracket holding the shelf as used would help.

Comment: @DavidD I'm guessing the single tab sticks _up_ into a slot, while the 2 tabs rest against the inside of the cabinet. The shelf then sits on the horizontal component.